# App structure for roles-based RESTful resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

Is there a consensus best approach to implementing user roles when using RESTful resource routes?

Say I have the following resources:

```
User has_many Tickets
Event has_many Tickets
Ticket belongs_to Person, Event
```

And then further say I have two types of Users: customers and agents.  Both will log into the system, but with different resource access and functionality based on their roles.  For example:

Customers can access:

- Event index, show
- Ticket index (scoped by user), show, buy/create, return/delete
- Person create, show, update

Agents can access:

- Event index, show, create, update, delete
- Ticket index, show, sell/create, update, refund/delete
- Person index, show, create, update, delete

Which of the 4 general approaches below will be cleaner and more flexible?

Separate controllers within role folders and resources in namespaces, eg:

```
namespace "agent" do
  resources :events, :tickets, :people
end
namespace "customer" do
  resources :events, :tickets, :people
end
```

Separate controllers by role, eg:

```
AgentController
  def sell_ticket, etc

CustomerController
  def buy_ticket, etc
```

Shared controllers with separate actions where needed, eg:

```
TicketController
  before_filter :customer_access, :only => :buy
  before_filter :agent_access, :except => :buy

  def buy  #accessed by customer to create ticket

  def sell   #accessed by agent to create ticket
```

Shared actions with conditional statements, eg:

```
TicketController
  def create
    if @role == :customer
      #buy ticket
    elsif @role == :customer
      #sell ticket
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using a combination of the last two proposed implementations. They adhere to RESTful representation, they put authorization at the appropriate level (controllers), and it is a scalable implementation.

REST is, essentially, about [accessing nouns with verbs](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife). So you want Agents and Customers to perform actions (verbs) in relation to Tickets, Users, and Events (nouns). In order to accurately represent these nouns you should have a controller for each. Customers can then identify the resource they are looking for by the URL, `http://example.com/events/22`. From here you can use Rails' routing to represent context for various resources, ie `http://example.com/events/22/tickets` by doing something like:

```
resource :events do
  resource :tickets
end
```

By adhering to a RESTful architecture, you are buying into the [end to end principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_principle). The paradigm for representing objects needs to be only responsible for that. It shouldn't try to authenticate. That isn't its job. Authorization should happen in the controllers. I would highly recommend looking into gems like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or [Declarative Authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) that set all of this up for you.

Finally, this model scalable. By keeping authorization separate from the representation of your resources you only have to use it if you need it. This keeps your application light, flexible, and simple.

Answer (score 0):

While they both deal with creating Tickets, the Agent / Ticket selling vs. the Customer / Ticket purchasing seem different enough to me that they should be separated. Eventually they could further diverge since they are being used so differently from the beginning.

It is possible to have shared controller functionality either with modules or by inheriting from a common parent controller:

```
module TicketsControllersCommom
  # common helper methods
end

class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  include TicketsControllersCommom
  # actions
end

class AgentTicketsController < ApplicationController
  include TicketsControllersCommom
  # actions
end
```

I might treat the agent parts as a sort of admin section, with the customer parts being the default:

```
/events/xx/tickets # collection
/events/xx/tickets/xx # member
# etc.
/events/xx/agent/tickets # collection
/events/xx/agent/tickets/xx # member
# etc.
```

Or, if you have a lot of admin-type stuff, like if the agents manage the events as well, you can namespace a whole section:

```
/agent/events/xx/tickets
/agent/events/xx/edit
# etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use the same model for customer and agent tickets, there should be no major difference between how they are handled in controller. So, create action will be always like this:

```
@ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket])

if @ticket.save
  redirect_to @ticket
else
  render :action => "new"
end
```

But your views can be simply customized:

```
<% if customer? %>
  Customer area.
<% else %>
  Agent area.
<% end %>
```

Comment: The model doesn't know about the user that has authenticated however.  That is usually managed by the controller.  Also, the OP is asking about the best way to handle security.  This can't be customised in views.  What about API connections?  How do you enforce security for different user roles there?  You don't want to repeat code, so it needs to be in a central place ie: controller.  So the question is, how can you sanely manage your controller to add this kind of fine control over user roles and permissions.